# Ember.js data issue

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am getting a `JSON` with this format from the server at this URL `localhost:8080/contractlines`:

```
{contractlines:[{"id":1,"site":"A","product":"B","price":200}]}
```

Following is my JS code:

```
window.App=Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    console.log('hello');
    // Set the IndexController's `title`
    controller.set('title', "My App");
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('contractlines');
});

App.Contractline=DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('number'),
  site: DS.attr('string'),
  product: DS.attr('string'),
  price:DS.attr('number')
});

App.ContractlinesRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    var tr=App.Contractline.find();
    console.log(tr);
    return tr;
  }
});
App.ContractlineController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

following is my HTML code:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
 <h1>contractlines</h1>
  {{outlet}}
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contractlines">
  {{#each contractline in controller}}
 <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
        {{#linkTo contractlines.contractline contractlines}}
       {{contractline.site}}
        {{/linkTo}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}


</script>
```

However no output when I visit `localhost:8080/webapp/testember.html#/contractlines` is generated though there is no error. I am successfully getting the `JSON` data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if that's the whole problem, but i think you need to move `{{#each contractline in controller}}` one line down (i.e. beneath the opening ul tag).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however after changing the same it didn't work.

Comment: hmm, have you tried visiting `localhost:8080/#/contractlines`? also, i think you need to change `ContractlineController` to `ContractlinesController`.

Comment: Hi Finh, thanks for your response.However changing ContractlineController to ContractlinesController has no effect.

Comment: maybe no visible effect, but if you don't rename it, it won't use your `ContractlinesRoute`. anyway, i fear i'm running out of ideas. sorry.

Comment: What I found is the response from the server was just a String not a JSON Object, when I changed the server code to return something like this:{
  "contractlines": [
    {
      "_id": "51403f68d3dc2955c8f1a9fd",
      "site": "A",
      "product": "B",
      "price": 2000
    }
  ]
}Then it worked